# W.r.t. Pass options to JPAAnnotationProcessor from Gradle

Tags: jpa, gradle, querydsl

I am using Gradle version 2.14, I have made changes in `build.gradle` to exclude packages from `JPAAnnotationProcessor` as mentioned in [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25918665/pass-options-to-jpaannotationprocessor-from-gradle).
My `build.gradle` configuration for same as follows:

```
configurations {

    querydslapt     
}


dependencies{
    compile group: 'com.querydsl', name: 'querydsl-core', version: '4.1.4'
    compile group: 'com.querydsl', name: 'querydsl-apt', version: '4.1.4'
    compile group: 'com.querydsl', name: 'querydsl-jpa', version: '4.1.4'

}

task generateQueryDSL(type: JavaCompile, group: 'build', description: 'Generates the QueryDSL query types') {

    source =sourceSets.main.java

    classpath = configurations.compile + configurations.querydslapt
    options.compilerArgs = [
            "-proc:only",
            "-processor", "com.querydsl.apt.jpa.JPAAnnotationProcessor",
            "-Aquerydsl.excludedPackages=com.projectx.data.domain.poc.lombok"            
    ]
    destinationDir = sourceSets.generated.java.srcDirs.iterator().next()
}

compileJava {
    dependsOn generateQueryDSL
    source generateQueryDSL.destinationDir
}

compileGeneratedJava {
    dependsOn generateQueryDSL
    options.warnings = false
    classpath += sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
}
```

But when I am building application I getting warning as `warning: The following options were not recognized by any processor: '[querydsl.excludedPackages]'`

And specified packages are not excluded from preprocessing.

Comment: I have the same issue! Have you found a solution for it?

Comment: @DaniilVolkov I was not able to find workaround for this in Gradle 2.14, I will now try it on Gradle 3.0 and let you know.

Answer (score 3):

Found a solution!

After adding `querydsl.entityAccessors=true` to aptOptions warning still present, but excluding packages works!

In your case, you should try add `-Aquerydsl.entityAccessors=true` to `options.compilerArgs =[]`
hope it helps

**UPDATED**

Just noticed that you use lombook in your project. 
Found this one ( [How to make QueryDSL and Lombok work together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44522494/how-to-make-querydsl-and-lombok-work-together) ) Hope it could be helpful for you!

Comment: Thanks for responding but above solution also not working for me.Now it giving warning as:The following options were not recognized by any processor: '[querydsl.entityAccessors, querydsl.excludedPackages]'

Comment: yes, warining is present for me too, but  excluding works

Comment: just noticed that you use lombook in your project. Found this one (
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44522494/how-to-make-querydsl-and-lombok-work-together) Hope it could be helpful for you

Comment: The solution mentioned in above link worked for me. Please edit answer previously given by you so that I can accept it. Thanks for helping, I owe you one answer to one of your query or a coffee may be.Saved lot of time